# Saving the End date

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a problem in my database i have a table called members and have two fields start_date and end_date..from the form people can enter the start date and from there i want to add three months the start_date to give the end_date

e.g

```
@member.end_date = params[:start_date] + 3months
```

can somebody please help me with this..Am using Rails3 by the way
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing a dot in your syntax.

```
@member.end_date = params[:start_date] + 3.months
```

Here's an example in irb (rails console):

```
$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.3)
> start_date = Time.now
 => 2011-01-29 17:18:58 +0000 
> end_date = start_date + 3.months
 => 2011-04-29 17:18:58 +0100
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `params[:start_date]` is a `Time` or `Date` object, you've pretty much got it right with your example. You just need to use `3.months` rather than `3months`.

```
@member.end_date = params[:start_date] + 3.months
```

As an aside, this logic should probably live in the model (your code looks like you're doing this in the controller)...

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_save :set_end_date

  private

    def set_end_date
      self.end_date = self.start_date + 3.months
    end

end
```